# Error on Starting a new Google Maps Activity in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

When I try to open a new Project with a Google Maps Activity Template I get these errors.

Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I am completely new to this, I tried looking at similar posts but I could not make sense to the explanations given there.

These errors are appearing in a file named google_maps_api.xml

Comment: On the top of Android studio there is a kind of command line(sorry for my English) go to build - clean and then build - rebuild

Comment: I tried clean build but the thing is that it is trying to find some sort of assets which are apparently not present. Is there a way to retrieve these or should i try to change the XML file?

Comment: Updated to the latest android studio version. problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to the latest android studio version. problem solved.